# Using tapply to calculate the mean of a group

Tags: r, statistics, tapply

In the following CSV file:

```
Species, Age
australian, 2.6
australian, 2.3
brown, 2.3
brown, 2.3
brown, 3.4
brown, 3.4
dalmatian, 5.1
dalmatian, 4.4
dalmatian, 4.4
dalmatian, 4.1
dalmatian, 4.2
dalmatian, 4.7
dalmatian, 5.5
```

I am attempting to calculate the mean for the Pelican species, but R is displaying an error about unequal lengths.

```
df <- read.csv('c:/Users/Michelle/Downloads/pelican.csv')
tapply(df$Species, df$Age, mean)
```

Error in tapply(df$Species, df$Age, mean) :
arguments must have same length

I assumed the tapply function would output each pelican species with the mean age of each.
Unfortunately, the director at the University of Florida is insisting I use base R functions.

Edit 1:

```
str(df) 'data.frame': 13 obs. of 2 variables: $ Species: chr "australian" "australian" "brown" "brown" ... $ Age : num 2.6 2.3 2.3 2.3 3.4 3.4 5.1 4.4 4.4 4.1 ... 

dput(df) structure(list(Species = c("australian", "australian", "brown", "brown", "brown", "brown", "dalmatian", "dalmatian", "dalmatian", "dalmatian", "dalmatian", "dalmatian", "dalmatian"), Age = c(2.6, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 3.4, 3.4, 5.1, 4.4, 4.4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.7, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Thank you Pedro for the help.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

M.

Comment: Uhmm...that is weird Michelle. I just copied the exact result of `dput(df)` that you added in the post, then when I run `tapply()`, it works. Please, try to run again the command: `tapply(df$Age, df$Species, mean)`

Comment: 1. I am not able to reproduce the error. When I use your data and the code I get `NA` values with lot of warnings. 2. You should change the order of `tapply` i.e try `tapply(df$Age, df$Species, mean)`

Comment: Thank you @Ronak. I switched the column vectors and the code functions as expected, but if I run it through knitr, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Michelle! The `tapply` function works with two main objets (these objects need to be vectors), called `X` and `INDEX`. What the error messages is telling you, is that `X` and `INDEX` does not have the same length.

The example below, reproduces the same error that you are facing. See that the `X` object have 4 elements, but `INDEX` have only 2.

```
tapply(X = c(5, 6, 7, 8), INDEX = c(1, 2), mean)
```

This means that, to fix your error, the first and second objects that you pass to `tapply()`, need to have the same length. In your example, these two objects are `df$Species` and `df$Age`. You can confirm if `df$Species` and `df$Age` does not have the same length, by comparing the result of `length(df$Species)` and `length(df$Age)`. If they are equal, then, these two vectors have the same length. But, if they are not equal, then these two vectors have different lengths.

What is probably going wrong in your code, is that the `read.csv()` function is not correctly reading your CSV file. Maybe `df` was transformed to a list, and not a `data.frame`. We cannot give better help than this for you, because we do not know what the `df` object is, or, how it is structured in your R session.

You could give these useful information for us, by copying and pasting the result of `str(df)` command, or, `dput(df)`. Both of these commandos would give us enough information to probably point out exactly what you need to do. So, next time, when you post a question, is good idea to include these infos.

Anyway, when I copy and paste the CSV file that you passed, and try to run your code, everything works fine. So, again, your `df` object is probably not structured as you expected, probably because of some problem at the `read.csv()` function.

```
text <- "
Species, Age
australian, 2.6
australian, 2.3
brown, 2.3
brown, 2.3
brown, 3.4
brown, 3.4
dalmatian, 5.1
dalmatian, 4.4
dalmatian, 4.4
dalmatian, 4.1
dalmatian, 4.2
dalmatian, 4.7
dalmatian, 5.5"

data <- readr::read_csv(text)
tapply(data$Age, data$Species, mean)
```

**Result:**

```
australian      brown  dalmatian 
  2.450000   2.850000   4.628571
```

Comment: Thank you Pedro. I included the output to the original post.